# push notification does not work using the web

Tags: android, ios, web-services, push-notification, token

I wanna to send a push to an Android phone ( using `GCM`) and iOS phone ( using `APNS`) .I wanna to send  it via my `backoffice` so I've  testing my web service via poster plugin and it works , I've receive that notification.

But when I  send it using my `backoffice` , It does not work .

do I have  to use an other library  for the web to send my notification to a mobile phone ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the PushNotification with PostManClient itself in Android. Just follow the below procedures.

```
1)Use the Post method for the below URL.

 https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

2) Just add Header as below

'Authorization: key=' Your Google API Key,
 'Content-Type: application/json'

3)Add the parameter as
{
 "registration_ids" : "Your GCM registration Key",
 "data" : "Your Messager"

}
```

You will receive the notification in GCMIntentService.

Comment: No , It ok ,on using the postermanClient but it does not work using this function using my backoffice